# Argument to JS Function Different Output using ' ' or " " or `${ }`

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I'm working on an Electron application and I am having some difficulty passing an Argument to a JS function losing the `/` character and causing strings to become lower case. A simplified view of my code is below.

```
let game_item = 'start "F:\/Riot Games/VALORANT/live/VALORANT.exe" --launch-product=valorant';

let insertLaunch = `<a href='#' onclick='consoleGameLaunch("${game_item}")'>Play</a>`;

document.getElementById('game-container').innerHTML += insertLaunch;
```

Now depending on how I wrap the `game_item` variable the rendered HTML will be completely different. Below is what I've tried and how it looks.

```
//JS try 1
insertLaunch = `<a href='#' onclick='consoleGameLaunch("${game-item}")'>
//HTML output
<a href="#" onclick="consoleGameLaunch(" start "F:\/Riot Games/VALORANT/live/VALORANT.exe" --launch-product=valorant")">
//JS try 2
insertLaunch = "<a href='#' onclick='consoleGameLaunch('"+game_item+"')'>
//HTML output
<a href="#" onclick="consoleGameLaunch("start "f:\ riot games valorant live valorant.exe" --launch-product="valorant')'">
```

Using the Dev console I can get this working by manually calling

```
consoleGameLaunch('start "F:\/Riot Games/VALORANT/live/VALORANT.exe" --launch-product=valorant');
```

How would I get that command to display properly in the HTML?

Comment: use the double quotes but escape them with ` \\ . Plus, I seriously doubt you can "get this working by manually calling" that syntax error with the extra quote (` ' `)

Comment: Recommendation: Use proper DOM APIs instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: @RandyCasburn You are absolutely right, that wouldn't have worked. That's what I get for rushing, I edited my post to reflect the actual working code. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to escape a value like that before turning it into a string, is to just let the JSON.stringify() function handle it.

For example:

```js
let game_item = 'start "F:\\/Riot Games/VALORANT/live/VALORANT.exe" --launch-product=valorant';

let insertLaunch = `<a href='#' onclick='consoleGameLaunch(${JSON.stringify(game_item)})'>Play</a>`;

window.consoleGameLaunch = function(msg) {
  console.log(msg)
}

document.getElementById('game-container').innerHTML += insertLaunch;
```

```html
<div id="game-container">
</div>
```

JSON.stringify() with a string value will return back a string that properly escapes quotes, so that you can add it to other strings.

Also, remember when writing a string literal that has a '' in it, you have to use two: '\'

See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp), which explains a little more about escaping string literals (among other things), it would be good to read up on that a bit.

As a final note, remember to be very careful using .innerHTML to create content. It's always safer to use other DOM API functions to create your content (like document.createElement())

Comment: This worked perfectly, appreciate the resources and will absolutely start using other API functions in the future, thanks